# Mongo connection in PHP session

Tags: php, ajax, mongodb, session

I'm currently working on an application which fires Ajax about 4 times in sec. PHP file has to connect to MongoDB every time Ajax is fired. It sometimes results in setting up additional 3 mongo connections (according to live server logs).
How am I supposed to establish one connection during PHP session without the need of setting up new ones?

Answer (score 1):

The number of connections actually isn't a problem. The drivers actually establish a connection pool. In replica sets and sharded clusters there are administrative connections, too. Having multiple connections isn't a problem.

While knowing quite some about MongoDB, I am not a PHP specialist. But as far as I know, there are no application level variables in PHP. So afaik, there is no method to store a connection(pool) on application level.

What most likely happens is that you open a connection in a php file and for one reason or the other this connection is kept open by the server because a server side cursor is still attached to the connection. Let us call these orphaned connections. Those orphaned connections are torn down by the server after 10 minutes.

The limit of connections a mongod / mongos instance can take is 20.000. So there are a lot of connections you can use. Nevertheless you should make sure that you either exhaust those cursors (after which they are torn down automatically) or tear them down manually with

```
$cursor->reset();
```

at the end of your function / method / source file. Otherwise you might run into problems when your application gets a lot of users.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Sessions are written to a file, using a format similar to `serialize()`, when your script exits (or calls `session_write_close()`) — as such, they cannot store [PHP resource objects](http://php.net/language.types.resource), such as database connections.

If you're seeing multiple Mongo connections per request, you probably aren't running a current version of the PHP MongoDB extension — current versions (1.3 or later) automatically pool connections across requests. Update to a current version of the driver, and no further work should be necessary.